# Resizing transparent jpeg generates image with black background

Tags: imageresizer

I am resizing images using **Image Resizer**. Everything's working as expected except one of our clients posted transparent jpeg, and resizing that image to 64*64 dimensions generates an image with black background. However, it works fine if the dimensions are larger like 1024.

```
    var instructions = new Instructions
        {
            Height = 64,
            Mode = FitMode.Max,
            OutputFormat = "jpeg",
            Width = 64
        };

    var job = new ImageJob(inputStream, outputStream, instructions);

    job.DisposeSourceObject = false;

    job.InstructionsAsString += "&fastscale=true";

    job.Build();
```

Comment: There is possible your client rename a PNG file to JPEG? And you not identify this action in pre-processing this file?

Comment: I agree with this, but not sure why then its working as expected for all larger dimensions?

Comment: My point is because the black background! This is probably one .png file renamed to .jpg.

Comment: There is a way to generate transparent jpegs and we cannot stop our clients to upload them and if its working fine for larger dimensions, it should work for small ones too.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there's no such thing as a "transparent jpeg".

Comment: Thanks for reply guys, much appreciated. But I think we can more concentrate on the the fact that whatever image type is, it is transparent and it is being resized to all larger dimensions but not the small ones. You can reply if you have answer to this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"fastscale=true" was creating a problem in my case. So for all heights and widths that are greater than 75, it works as expected.

So I added following check to not include it for small dimensions

if (height >= 75 && width>= 75)
{

```
job.InstructionsAsString += "&fastscale=true";
```

}